# Angular change detection on input decorated property

Tags: angular, templates, input, properties, angular2-changedetection

If I decorate my property with @Input decorator and update it via some rest service, will a string interpolated property in a template be updated every time it changes?

In a component:

```
@Input()
myProperty: string;
```

In a template:

```
{{myProperty}}
```

Comment: The `@Input` decorator accepts values from the parent component and updates depending on your [change detection strategy](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#usage-notes). What do you mean by "update it via some rest service"? Is one of the components calling a service that's making an HTTP request?

Comment: Hmm... yes. Did you try ?

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I can't try right now. Every example talks about child and parent and binding, that's why I ask what about updating property via service and not parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@Input` to bind a value from a service (`@Injectable`), as `@Input` is specifically for passing values from a parent component to a child component via the parent's template:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-parent',
    template: `<app-child [name]='name'></app-child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {
    name: string = "World";
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `<p>Hello, {{name}}!</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() name: string;
}
```

You could [bind to an `Observable`](https://angular.io/guide/observables) using the [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) (here I've created an `Observable` from a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject), but it could just as easily be returned from a method that makes an HTTP request via [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient)):

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NameService implements OnInit {
    private name = new BehaviorSubject('');
    public name$ = this.name.asObservable();

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.name.next('World');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-child',
    template: `<p>Hello, {{nameService.name$ | async}}!</p>`
})
export class ChildComponent {    
    constructor(public nameService: NameService) { }
}
```